# Using method 'pmm' while simultaneously exluding variables from imputation

Tags: r, prediction, r-mice

I am currently imputing data with the R package mice, using the 'pmm' method.
Minimum working example (given dataset loaded and variables properly specified):

```
library(mice)
Example_imp <- mice(Example_data, m = 5, maxit = 50, method = "pmm", seed = 500)
```

I further want to exclude some variables from imputation (sociodemographic variables). They should be used as predictors but there are no missing values for them, which is why no imputation is necessary for them. I found a way to specify the method so that the specified variables are excluded from imputation:

```
init <- mice(Example_data, maxit = 0) 
meth <- init$method
meth[c("Age", "Nationality", "Gender", "Educ")]=""
Example_imp2 <- mice(Example_data, m = 5, maxit = 50, method = meth, seed = 500)
```

But when I impute data, I can specify "method" only once, that is, either I specify `method = "pmm"` or `method = meth`. I cannot "double-specify" it. So how can I use the pmm method why still excluding some variables from imputation and only use them as predictors?

Comment: If there are no missing values in these variables then they won't be imputed. No specification is necessary, this is a default setting of `mice`. p19 Van Buuren & Groothuis-Oudshoorn (2011) "Since age contains no missing data, mice() silently sets all values in the row to 0.". Check the `init$method` object, these variables should have `meth ""` by default

Comment: Thanks, Niek! That sounds plausible

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a predictorMatrix value in mice()

For example, the nhanes dataset:

```
   age  bmi hyp chl
1   1   NA  NA  NA
2   2 22.7   1 187
3   1   NA   1 187
4   3   NA  NA  NA
```

The default predictor matrix where all variables are used for imputation looks like:

```
     age hyp chl
age   0   1   1
hyp   1   0   1
chl   1   1   0
```

If, for example, imputation of chl is not needed then we need to make the chl row all 0 then set the following to be your predictorMatrix

```
    age hyp chl
age   0   1   1
hyp   1   0   1
chl   0   0   0
```

Comment: Thank you, ist123! But I thought the predictormatrix is used to remove or add variables as predictors. On the following website (https://datascienceplus.com/handling-missing-data-with-mice-package-a-simple-approach/) I found the an example: The code below will remove the variable as a predictor but still will be imputed. Just for illustration purposes, I select the BMI variable to not be included as predictor during imputation.

predM[, c("BMI")]=0 

What I need is quite the opposite: Use a variable as a predictor but no imputation for this variable.Or did I get something completely wrong?